# VBA (Excel) updating ActiveRow when extending range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm making a macro in Excel to append the number of the row of the cell to the date in yyyymmdd format to generate fake barcodes with checksums. The first part uses the current date multiplied by 10000 and adding the current row number:

```
Public Function CreateBarcode() As Double

Dim BCode As Double

BCode = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd")
BCode = BCode * 10000
BCode = BCode + ActiveCell.Row

CreateBarcode = BCode
End Function
```

The function works if I explicitly call it in the cell and press Enter. However if I call it in cell A1 and then extend the selection down (using the black cross in the bottom corner of the cell) it retains the original Row number and so all the numbers generated are identical.

How can I code it so that rather than use ActiveCell it uses the actual row number of where it is?

Comment: Indeed, the ActiveCell refers to the cell where you are currently. What about adding  a `Range("A1").Select`Range("A1").Select then `Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion`Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to pass the Cell you want (as Range) to check the value for, to your Function.

So let's say you wan't to use it for Cell A1, with reference to Cell A1, you need to type in the following formula:

```
=CreateBarcode(A1)
```

Then, you can drag it down for the rest of the cells in Column A.

Below you can find edited code for your function with the Cell refernece passed:

```
Public Function CreateBarcode(cellRef As Range) As Double

Dim BCode As Double

BCode = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd")
BCode = BCode * 10000
BCode = BCode + cellRef.Row

CreateBarcode = BCode

End Function
```

Below you can find a screen-shot with the Sheet results (after implementing the changes above):

[image]